# What to do if user frequently toggles accepted state of my answer

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, etiquette

Some time ago, I wrote an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39327624/982149) to a question, that got accepted. During the last few days, the OP unaccepted, accepted and unaccepted again the answer ...

I am totally okay if they somehow decides that the answer wasn't as helpful as they initially thought. But the toggling is starting to be a pain.

What can I possibly do? This behavior is somewhat annoying.

---

UPDATE / CLARIFICATIONS

Some Points in response to comments:

- I am aware that it is the OP's right to unaccept my answer and I am totally OK with that fact.
- He did that for 3 or 4 times, I don't remember exactly because he's doing that in a frequency that is just long enough to "forget" about it. So each time I am alerted anew and try to figure out why he could have felt urged to unaccept. So it is not so much that he is doing that with a high frequency.
- I considered deleting the answer (and I am considering that right now) but I am hesitant to do so, because I still think the answer could be helpful for other users. Also, not knowing the reason for this - it could as well be he finally will decide to accept it and I don't want to deprive him of that option.
- My question here on meta is not so much because of this specific incident. It was the trigger, yes. But I wanted to know how I can deal with this kind of situation generally.
- I don't know if locking the answer would be a solution ( I didn't even know that this was possible) and I am not interested in *forcing* him to do anything (or not to). I'd rather have him understand the results of his actions and why this is annoying to others (in this case me).
- *I do not want to make any accusations about the OP*. I really don't think it is bad will behind his actions. Though, if we abstract from this specific incident, there could be other cases where there is trolling or causing annoyance purposefully involved.

Comment: @rottenoats I am interested in a "peaceful" solution ;)

Comment: Leaving a comment like the one you just left might be the only thing you can do but you may want to point out that you're getting notifications when they do this. That makes it clearer that the issue is that their behavior is "noisy". Right now you've requested that they stop but you didn't explain why it's a problem.

Comment: @BSMP : Very good point. I'll do that.

Comment: I don't think the OP received your comment on your answer since the OP hasn't commented at all. You should post the comment below the question instead. (but it seems OP has stopped their behavior?)

Comment: @AndrewT. Fildor tagged OP correctly so there is nothing wrong on his side and OP doesn't need to comment anyway. Writing another comment under the question would just be noise.

Comment: @Tom AFAIK, one cannot tag someone if they haven't commented on/edited the post, but I don't know if you can tag OP or not after accepting an answer.

Comment: @AndrewT. is right - ["if Alice was the author of the question, then you cannot notify her by commenting on Bob's answer (unless Alice also participated in that answer)"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work).

Comment: Delete your answer.

Comment: Can you eventually flag for moderator intervention and request that the post be locked?

Comment: @EJoshuaS If an answer is locked, [it cannot be upvoted anymore](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22229). I don't think it's a good idea to lock it. On the other hand, I'm not sure if a locked answer can be accepted/unaccepted.

Comment: I would swear that this has been discussed before, but I can't find the right search terms to bring it up, either here or on the uber-Meta. The real solution, of course, is a [feature-request] to introduce a bit of hysteresis into the notification system, making this less annoying to the victim (and thus not a vehicle for trolling).

Comment: @CodyGray I searched, too. I didn't want my first meta-question to be a dupe :) As to a feature-request: I don't feel experienced enough to conclude such a measure needs to be taken, especially not based on this specific incident. I don't think the "perpetrator" is doing this on purpose with the goal to troll me or cause annoyance. He is rather low-rep, so I think he is simply not aware of all the consequences that arise when ticking or unticking that mark. But of course, looking at it more generally, in other cases this may well be the case.

Comment: I don't see how this is an issue that needs addressing

Comment: @Isaac I do not say it does.  I just wanted to know what Options I have in case it gets worse and in general unrelated to this specific case.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I agree with the other users here. The question asker is well within their rights to un-accept and accept a different answer. *If they've only done this several times, then I still think they're within their rights, and you should simply move on*.

However, if the OP continues to do this to the point where it becomes a problem, a polite comment alerting them of the problem seems like the best, fastest, and easiest solution :

> I understand that you may be trying to decide whether to accept my answer. However, you seem to be marking and then un-marking my answer quite frequently. [This causes me to be notified each time this occurs](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer), and has become a bit frustrating. A better course of action would be to decide which answer you want to select *without* switching your selection mark between answers. Once you have made your final decision, then mark an answer of your choice. Thank you.

(And yes, I checked. The above block-quote will fit into the comment box provided.)

Comment: I really didn't know how to answer that one. Your answer is very good. Kind of trick question which could have been asked to the candidates at every moderator election. Don't worry. In the end you'll get more upvotes, just because ... there's nothing more to do than leave a nice comment like this (well, you can also delete your answer :))

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yes, I realize that. I was wondering _why_ someone disagreed, though. Not so I could get in a fight, but to understand their perspective. I can understand though if some people prefer not to share their thoughts. Hmm, seems this just got another down-vote... Oh well.

Comment: I disagree. The OP has the right to change their mind. Two notifications is barely a source of frustration.

Comment: Okay @ayhan, I see what you mean. That's a very valid point. To be completely honest, I didn't read the question carefully enough to see that Fildor _literally_ meant the OP had only done this behavior twice. In that case, then I completely agree with you. I'll edit to clarify this. However, I still believe this answer would be beneficial in the cases where this behavior is actually a problem.

Comment: I don't see why this answer is downvoted. It is good advice after all. As you said @ayhan , it is not _really_ frustrating, **yet**. It is just a bit of an annoyance and I'll leave it at rest for now. But if he continues this behavior, I'll try as Chrsitian suggested with a comment like the suggested one to the question.

Comment: Really nice. I would consider taking out the *"Would you please refrain from this behavior?"* bit as referring to a "behavior" is an easy way to misread the entire thing. The comment works great without that personal request as it is intended to make one think rather than feel guilt.

Comment: @Gimby Hmm, okay. After thinking about for a bit, I agree with your point. It could already be implied by you contacting the OP that you want them to avoid the behavior. I'll remove that part.

Comment: @ChristianDean if it's not downvoted, then it's not a meta-post :) the aim is to get more upvotes than downvotes. And if you cannot... the aim is to get _some_ upvotes :)

Comment: I would add an alternative: just delete your answer and there's no epilepsy risk of seeing the +15 on and off 10 times per second on your dashboard :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre That's generally an option that exists. In my specific case I do not really want to do this. But I will reconsider it, if this happens again (and more frequently). So, I agree it would be good to mention that option in the answer.

Comment: @Fildor I was joking of course. But that works, for sure.